# Regex selector for jquery does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) but without success. I am on FFv47

I try to debug (F12)   and stop script execution around the line:

```
return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
```

When I enter watch expression: `jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property)`
I see `undefined`

When I enter watch expression: `jQuery(elem)[attr.method]('class')`
I see `'editor'` (as expected)

When I enter watch expression: `attr.property`
I see `'class'`

So I expect first watch expression to work and show me value `'editor'`

Why `jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property)` does not show me correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the specified blog post error.  You should replace this:

```
regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^s+|s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
```

by this (Notice `\` near `s+`)

```
regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
```

Also be carefull when you write selector:

```
$('script:regex( src,jQuery)');
```

If you occasionally put extra space as the example above the `_src` (count here `_` as whitespace) property would be tested instead of expected `src`.

This also may be cause of error.